# 64-bit Unix timestamp conversion

Tags: c++, linux, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, time-t

Is there any C++ implementation of 64-bit Unix timestamp conversions for 32-bit systems? I need to convert `struct tm` to 64-bit integer and vice versa, including leap years, time zones, UTC. Also need it portable, at least for GNU/Linux and Windows.

Comment: What should that timestamp represent? If its just seconds since epoch, then you can just use a 32bit conversion function and copy the result into a 64bit integer (as long as you are before 2038)

Comment: Isn't `time_t` already 64 bit on most systems? Windows has most functions also in a 64bit variant. Just google for it.

Comment: An integer cannot represent timezones as it's a relative offset from an arbitrary epoch (in UNIX that's Jan 01 1970), but the timezone is undefined.  If you want to represent these elements you'll have to break them down into a `struct` anyway.  Also no one 'represents' leap years; how would they?  Hold a meaningless count of them or something?

Comment: PlasmaHH: Exactly, just not before 2038

Comment: RedX: I belive that only on 64bit systems. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: trojanfoe: You are right, the integer cannot represent any of these. But you have to consider them when converting to `struct tm`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need:

```
typedef long long time64_t; 
time64_t mktime64(struct tm *t); 
struct tm* localtime64_r(const time64_t* t, struct tm* p);
```

Originally (in 2011) this answer contained links to 2038bug.com where it was possible to download the small `pivotal_gmtime_r` library, containing the mentioned functions. The library has been removed from 2038bug.com back then, the links became broken and were removed from the answer by a moderator. Seems like that `pivotal_gmtime_r` code can now be found here:

https://github.com/franklin373/mortage/tree/master/time_pivotal

Also, I've found another, more recent library, called `y2038`, that also implements `mktime64` and `localtime64_r`:

https://github.com/evalEmpire/y2038

Comment: This looks like a perfect solution for me. It just seems to me that mktime64 expects UTC in its parameter. Converting time_t to struct tm by localtime64_r and back using mktime64 doesn't give the original time, while converting time_t to struct tm by gmtime64_r and back by mktime64 does. Can you please confirm it?

Comment: Yes, confirming! `localtime` was mentioned so much in this thread that I mixed it up. :) Of course you need `gmtime64_r`.

Comment: But as I understand it, ‘mktime‘ should expect local time, doesn’t it?

Comment: Yes, seems like an inconsistency.  
  
Standard `mktime` expects local time and will supposedly get timezone from your local settings and convert it to `UTC`.  
  
But this `mktime64` is "timezone-agnostic". I.e. it will give you output `time64_t` in `UTC` if you supply input `struct tm` in `UTC`, output in `UTC+10` if you supply input in `UTC+10`, etc.

Comment: Where are those functions? `ack mktime64 /usr/include/` comes back blank on recent Linux

Comment: @dargaud, I have updated the answer with links and with some explanation.

Answer (score 7):

The function converting a `struct tm*` to a `time_t` is `mktime`. You can find many implementations of it, eg. in Glibc and in [libvxc's `mktime.c` file](http://vx32.googlecode.com/hg/src/libvxc/mktime.c). You could take the code (assuming it is legal to you, so please respect licenses) and change `time_t` to some 64 bits integer like `int64_t`.

The functions doing the other conversions from `time_t` to `struct tm*` are `localtime` or `gmtime` and you could do likewise.

However, you might have a more fundamental issue: your 32 bits machine running in the year 2040 should have some way of giving you the current time (as the `time` system call does) appropriately in the 64 bits variant of `time_t`, and that is much harder (it depends upon the kernel and the hardware).

Comment: Is there any implementation which handles `localtime` in a portable manner?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you call portable? `time_t` can be a 32 bits or a 64 bits integer type (so the machine code has to be different).

Comment: I was thinking about using sources. But when I went through some of them, they used non-standard built-in functions for determining timezone and DST

Comment: it is perfectly portable, but they don't care about a difference between UTC and local time

Comment: Also notice that in `mktime` they don't adjust ranges in `struct tm`

Comment: The version of mktime() that you've linked is very naive. Compare it, for example, with [`mktime()`](http://www.raspberryginger.com/jbailey/minix/html/mktime_8c-source.html) from minix.

Comment: +1, for my purposes `libvxc` is pretty good. And BTW, to fix thing with local->UTC conversion is just one line of code, so this is not an issue really.

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be making the assumption that `time_t` is 32-bits on 32-bit systems, and this may or may not be true.

On Windows, starting with Visual Studio 2005 the size of `time_t` is 64-bits, even when you compile for 32-bit Windows.

The unfortunate part is that glibc defines it as `long int`, which on 32-bit systems is a 32-bit integer. That means that 32-bit Linux and other 32-bit platforms that are based on gcc/glibc (like Cygwin) will not be able to work with 64-bit timestamps.

If your application must run on 32-bit glibc, then you should use your own conversion functions, which could be the same functions in the C library recompiled to use 64-bit timestamps.

If you need source code with a permissive license (BSD), then you can look at these functions in minix3. [Here](http://www.raspberryginger.com/jbailey/minix/html/localtime_8c-source.html) is localtime. The source is hyperlinked, so you can find the others easily.

Answer (score 0):

64-bit time support on 32-bit Linux was [first introduced in the **5.1 kernel**](https://lwn.net/Articles/776427/) with the addition of the new [`*time64` syscalls](https://lwn.net/ml/linux-kernel/20190110172216.313063-12-arnd@arndb.de/) (because changing the return type of old system calls breaks old applications). Check [this table](https://fedora.juszkiewicz.com.pl/syscalls.html) and you'll see that those syscalls are only available on 32-bit platforms.

But that's only support from the kernel side. You can call `clock_gettime64` directly (from inline assembly, or from C with [`syscall()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html) function) to get the current time but you'll need Linux-specific code because there's no glibc support yet. For full *userspace* support you must be on **Linux 5.6 or higher** along with musl 1.2+ or glibc 2.32+. Just rebuild your code and `time_t` will become 64-bit long. Now code that uses `time_t` will become completely portable

> - All user space must be compiled with a 64-bit `time_t`, which will be supported in the coming musl-1.2 and glibc-2.32 releases, along with installed kernel headers from linux-5.6 or higher.
> - Applications that use the system call interfaces directly need to be ported to use the `time64` syscalls added in linux-5.1 in place of the existing system calls. This impacts most users of `futex()` and `seccomp()` as well as programming languages that have their own runtime environment not based on libc.
>
> https://lkml.org/lkml/2020/1/29/355?anz=web

For more information read

- [Approaching the kernel year-2038 end game](https://lwn.net/Articles/776435/)
- Discussion on how to solve [Y2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem): [2038 is closer than it seems](https://lwn.net/Articles/599580/)
- [64-bit time symbol handling in the GNU C Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/64_002dbit-time-symbol-handling.html)
- [glibc Y2038 Proofness Design](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Y2038ProofnessDesign)
- [Change time_t and clock_t to 64 bit](https://lwn.net/Articles/598408/)

Answer (score -1):

Yeah use `stuct tm *_localtime64  ( const __time64_t *timer);`

That's if your windows fan.

Comment: Perfect solution for windows, but as I mention in the question, I need both windows and linux

Comment: There is something called ifndef.. use that.

Comment: True, true. Byt my rule of thumb is to forget about conditional compilation unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: `_localtime64_s` is safer BTW